# PowerShell running a system command with arguments that include "/"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a simple system command:
***dir c:\Temp /ar*** from a PowerShell script using "&", Invoke-Expression, Invoke-Command but looks like PowerShell does not really like the forward slash "/".
I've also tries to escape it using "" or "`" but to no avail...

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

`dir` is neither a PowerShell command nor a native executable - it's a built-in command in *cmd.exe* - so you need to invoke `cmd.exe`:

```
& cmd /c dir c:\Temp /ar
```

---

PowerShell aliases `dir` to its own `Get-ChildItem` command - and `Get-ChildItem` will interpret `/ar` as a rooted path argument, thus attempting to list the directory contents at `/ar` (or `C:\ar` on Windows), which is probably what you're currently experiencing.

To list read-only items with the `Get-ChildItem` command, use the `-Attributes` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes ReadOnly
```

Which can conveniently be shortened to:

```
Get-ChildItem -ar
```

So you can also solve your problem by simply using `-ar` instead of `/ar`:

```
dir c:\Temp -ar
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use commands such as `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem`. Remember that `Get-Item` will throw a fatal error while `ChildItem` will error silently.

Comment: Both `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem` behave the same with respect to errors: Unless there's a _syntax error_ during invocation (e.g. `Get-Item -NoSuchParam`), the errors they report are _non-terminating_. You only get silent behavior  - with either cmdlet - with _wildcard_ arguments (`-Path` parameter) that happen not to match anything (which isn't an error condition).